# How to resize image by using seekbar?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-resizing, android-seekbar

I want to resize image by using seekbar. Seekbar is working but its not giving any good results. With the following code, the image is resized but just when you change the progress of seekbar for the first time. Please help

Seekbar listener

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progresValue = progress;
            resizeImage(image, progresValue);
        }
    });
```

Function to resize image

```
public void resizeImage(Bitmap bitmap, int progress) {
    Bitmap bitmapSource = bitmap;
    float bHeight = bitmapSource.getHeight();
    float bWidth = bitmapSource.getWidth();
    float factorH = progress / (float) bHeight;
    float factorW = progress / (float) bWidth;
    float factorToUse = (factorH > factorW) ? factorW : factorH;
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapSource,
            (int)(bWidth * factorToUse), (int)(bHeight * factorToUse),
            false);
    qImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: I would guess the main problem is this line: `progresValue = progress;`.

Comment: remove progresValue = progress; this line and check again.

Comment: go to herer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968514/scale-bitmap-through-seekbar
same question and show my ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final SeekBar sk1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
                sk1.setMax(500);
                 sk1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

                                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                                }       

                                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

                                }       

                                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      



                     img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(progress,progress);
                      img.setLayoutParams(params);

                      img.setMinimumWidth(progress);
                      img.setMinimumHeight(progress);






                                }       
                            });
```